# Overload list syntax for functions with the same name but different number of arguments

Tags: typescript

Let's assume some interface exists such that it has two functions, both of the same name but with a different number of arguments.

```
interface IMyInterface<T> {
    someFunction(event: string, callback: (data: T, context: any) => any): this;
    someFunction(callback: (data: T, context: any) => any): this;
}
```

In TypeScript, this is a perfectly valid declaration and compiles just fine. When you try to implement it, that's when things get tricky.

Consider the following:

```
class MyClassImp<T> implements IMyInterface<T> {

    public someFunction(event: string | undefined, callback: Callback<T>): this {
        return this;
    }

}
```

To me this makes sense because either `event` exists as the first parameter or it doesn't, and then there's `callback`.

The JavaScript generated makes sense as well:

```
var MyClassImp = (function () {
    function MyClassImp() {
    }
    MyClassImp.prototype.someFunction = function (event, callback) {
        return this;
    };
    return MyClassImp;
}());
```

where inside the function body you might write something like `event = event || ""` or `if (event) { // do this } else { // do this }`.

Surprisingly, this fails to compile with the TypeScript compiler (version 2.7.1) with this config:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noErrorTruncation": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "allowJs": false,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "declaration": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es5",
        "pretty": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "test/**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

The error thrown is:

```
Property 'someFunction' in type 'MyClassImp<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'IMyInterface<T>'.
  Type '(event: string | undefined, callback: Callback<T>) => this' is not assignable to type '{ (event: string, callback: Callback<T>): this; (callback: Callback<T>): this; }'.
```

Why is it failing to compile? Anyone have insight here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation signature must be compatible with all overload declarations, and argument names do not matter for compatibility - only types and order of arguments is taken into account. So the first argument must be either string or callback, and second argument must be optional:

```
interface IMyInterface<T> {
    someFunction(event: string, callback: (data: T, context: any) => any): this;
    someFunction(callback: (data: T, context: any) => any): this;
}

class MyClassImp<T> implements IMyInterface<T> {

    public someFunction(event: string | ((data: T, context: any) => any), callback?: (data: T, context: any) => any): this {
        return this;
    }

}
```

Also, if different overloaded variants return different types, you have to repeat all overload declarations in the class:

```
interface IMyInterface<T> {
    someFunction(event: string, callback: (data: T, context: any) => any): string;
    someFunction(callback: (data: T, context: any) => any): number;
}

class MyClassImp<T> implements IMyInterface<T> {


  someFunction(event: string, callback: (data: T, context: any) => any): string;
  someFunction(callback: (data: T, context: any) => any): number;
  someFunction(event: string | ((data: T, context: any) => any), callback?: (data: T, context: any) => any): string | number {
                return callback ? '1' : 2;
    }

}

var t = new MyClassImp<string>();

const s = t.someFunction('w', (data, content) => 2); // string

const n = t.someFunction((data, content) => 2); // number
```

Comment: Which is more technically correct, your version or @Tao's? Both compile and satisfy the interface requirement.

Comment: I just checked one more time - only the implementation is necessary. I updated my answer, it's now no different from @Tao's

Comment: Actually I think your previous answer was better, I just checked it in the playground and if you don't provide the overload signatures in the class only the implementation signature is available on instances.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly reorganizing the code can simplify things and also fix the errors:

```
type Callback<T> = (data: T, context: any) => any;

interface IMyInterface<T> {
    someFunction(callback: Callback<T>, event: string): this;
    someFunction(callback: Callback<T>): this;
}

class MyClassImp<T> implements IMyInterface<T> {
    someFunction(callback: Callback<T>, event: string): this;
    someFunction(callback: Callback<T>): this;
    someFunction(callback: Callback<T>, event?: string): this {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Pay attention to arguments order - callback is required in both overloads, so it is better to put it first and then the optional event.

Also you can omit overloads in implementation (if you want to):

```
class MyClassImp<T> implements IMyInterface<T> {
    someFunction(callback: Callback<T>, event?: string): this {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that one time `callback` is the first argument and the other time it is the second argument but in your implementation it is always the second argument.

You need an implementation signature like this:

```
someFunction(eventOrCallback: string | Callback<T>, callback?: Callback<T>): this
```

And then test in the method body if `eventOrCallback` is `string` or not.

Comment: How come it doesn't require putting the two other overloads before this in an overload list? Both versions compile, I'm curious as to which one is the better way of doing things